# JSF Validation message not displaying in template's content part

Tags: html, jsf

I got problem with non displaying validation error message on my form, when I'm using templates.

It does validation ok, as I can see I am not forwarded to next page, but I dont see error message.

When I try same code without defining layout template parts it prints message.

This is my **form** code:

```
<h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel for="mname">Username&nbsp;</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText required="true" requiredMessage="Username is required.">

            </h:inputText>                                
            <h:commandButton value="Submit"></h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

And this is my code when I'm **defining content** part:

```
        <!-- Content -->
        <ui:define name="content">               
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputLabel for="mname">Username&nbsp;</h:outputLabel>
                    <h:inputText required="true" requiredMessage="Username is required.">

                    </h:inputText>                                
                    <h:commandButton value="Submit"></h:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
```

Anyone got reason why wouldn't I see error message when I'm defining my layout page.

This is my layout.xhtml content part.

```
<div id="content">
        <ui:insert name="content">
            <ui:include src="/template/content.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
</div>
```

Comment: and where do you define <h:message> tag?

Comment: It works with h:message Maciej thanks a lot. You can post answer so I mark it as final answer.

Comment: Cool.. i have posted the answer so that others can benefit as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually you will need a h:message tag.. the requiredMessage is a tip for the framework on what to print in the message tag.

So you should have a set up like:

```
<h:form>
    <h:message showSummary="true" showDetail="false"
        id="errorsMessages"
        for="txt"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel for="mname">Username&nbsp;</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="txt" required="true" requiredMessage="Username is required.">

            </h:inputText>                                
            <h:commandButton value="Submit"></h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```